# How to access static root from a sub route inside a Node JS Express application?

Tags: node.js, express

The code in server.js (the Node entrypoint) is

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const publicFilePath = __dirname + '/public';

app.use(express.static(publicFilePath));

const api = require('./routes/api');

app.use('/api', api);


const router = express.Router()


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  //res.send("hello world");
  res.render("index.html", { "a": "Hello", "b": "World" });
});




app.listen(3080, () => {
  console.log("App listening on port 3080");
});
```

and /routes/api.js contains

```
const express = require('express')


const router = express.Router()

router.post("/upload-file", async (req, res) => {
  let file = req.files.file;
  console.log(req.static); // this line evaluates to undefined
  const mediaFilePath = req.static.root + '/media'; // This line crashes
  

  console.log("File uploaded");
  res.json({successful: true});
});

module.exports = router
```

The Node JS application crashes on the line shown above

I was expecting req.static.root to be defined and have to have the value set in the server.js file inside express.static(...).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such property as req.static in Express. Instead, you can use req.app.get('static root') to retrieve the value you set in the express.static() middleware in your server.js file.
First in your server.js file, you need to set the value of the static root path

```js
// Set the static root path
app.set('static root', publicFilePath)

app.use(express.static(publicFilePath))
```

you can then retrieve it within your routes to access the path for your media files.

```js
router.post("/upload-file", async (req, res) => {
    const staticRoot = req.app.get('static root')
    const mediaFilePath = staticRoot + '/media'
    console.log(mediaFilePath)
    //... rest of your code
})
```

Comment: Ok, that does seem to work but I presume that means I have to set the variable inside of every sub route that needs it?  Or can it be set at the module level?

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question so the answer might be wrong. It is being set at module level and available throughout your entire application, including all the sub routes and middlewares. You can export the app from server.js then import it where ever you want and call app.get('static root'). If your concern is repeating yourself, you can create a middleware to get the static root and attach it to the request object so it could be accessed from controller with req.static or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what I mean.